# References, Suttas, on the effects of rejecting (gifts)

Tags: reference-request, sutras, dana

Just wonder if there are explicitly teachings on cause and effect of rejecting gifts. What might be the effect of rejecting a pure gift? Maybe one or another Sutta may come to your mind and maybe you like to share it in an answer.

Gift here can be in the frame of material gifts, to time, effort, skill and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I can recall there is a Sutta where a monk reject the robes offered to hims as he had plenty of robes.

Comment: Angulimala Sutta http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.086.than.html

Comment: What was the effect Nyom Sarath? Is it just a side story or does it transport a teaching?

Answer (score 0):

AN 9.5 states:

> *And what, monks, is the power of benevolence? There are four ways of benevolence; by gifts, by friendly speech, by helpful acts and by
>   bestowal of equity. This is the best of gifts: the gift of Dhamma. And
>   this is the best of friendly speech: to teach again and again Dhamma
>   to those who wish for it and who listen attentively. And this is the
>   best of helpful acts: to arouse, instil and strengthen faith in the
>   unbeliever; to arouse, instil and strengthen virtue in the immoral; to
>   arouse, instil and strengthen generosity in the niggard; to arouse,
>   instil and strengthen wisdom in the unwise. And this is the best
>   bestowal of equity: if a stream-winner becomes equal to a
>   stream-winner; a once-returner equal to a once-returner; a
>   non-returner equal to a non-returner; and an arahant equal to an
>   arahant. This, monks, is called the power of benevolence.*

Therefore, the attempt to give a mundane dhamma gift to a supramundane stream-winner (or higher) is to be rejected.

This is similar to what occurred in MN 140, when the gift of *metta* by (the unknowing) Pukkusati of calling the Buddha "friend" was later deemed to be inappropriate, thus rejected & the object of confession.

> *Then the thought occurred to Ven. Pukkusati: "Surely, the Teacher has come to me! Surely, the One Well-gone has come to me! Surely, the
>   Rightly Self-awakened One has come to me!" Getting up from his seat,
>   arranging his upper robe over one shoulder, and bowing down with his
>   head at the Blessed One's feet, he said, "A transgression has overcome
>   me, lord, in that I was so foolish, so muddle-headed, and so unskilled
>   as to assume that it was proper to address the Blessed One as
>   'friend.' May the Blessed One please accept this confession of my
>   transgression as such, so that I may achieve restraint in the
>   future."*
>
> *Yes, monk, a transgression overcame you in that you were so foolish, so muddle-headed, and so unskilled as to assume that it was proper to
>   address me as 'friend.' But because you see your transgression as such
>   and make amends in accordance with the Dhamma, we accept your
>   confession. For it is a cause of growth in the Dhamma & Discipline of
>   the noble ones when, seeing a transgression as such, one makes amends
>   in accordance with the Dhamma and achieves restraint in the future.*